# Google Assistant on my phone recognises appointments from multiple calendars, but Google Home does not

Tags: google-calendar, google-assistant

If I 'OK Google' into my phone to ask what meetings I have that day, it is able to show me the calendar entries from my work calendar (which is also a Google Calendar, but not my personal account) as I have linked that calendar to my phone.

However, my Google Home is not aware of any events on calendars other than my personal one so will give me a different answer to the question than my phone does.

How can I get Google Home to recognise entries in other linked Google calendars?

Comment: According to this Google help page, it's not possible: https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7029002?hl=en

Comment: @JT.  Damn, looks like you're right. I guess I need to find a way to replicate calendar entries from one calendar into the other then, so that everything is in my personal calendar.

Comment: Just found this in my news feed: https://lifehacker.com/how-to-manage-multiple-calendars-with-google-home-1820653306

Comment: @JT. Hmm, interesting. I don't have it available (yet) but feel free to post an answer with that content as it seems like that's going to be the way to do it in the near future.